# Library to calculate object detection metrics

Tags: computer-vision, object-recognition

I am working on a project where I have to calculate the MAP (Mean Average Precision), Precision, Recall, etc. from object detection. In my case, it is a single-class object detection where more than one object of the same class can appear in a single image. I didn't find any method to calculate the popular metrics as aforementioned related to object detection with the help of `opencv`. Is there any prominent library that I can use for this purpose? I want a library that will calculate all of these metrics and I shall provide the ground truth box(es) and predicted box(es) positions for each image.